# JqueryUI tooltip on button click instead of hover to appear elsewhere

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using ***JQueryUI tooltip*** to display some dynamic messages to the user. Basically I want to display the tooltip on top of an input field when a user clicks a button.

The way I have coded it works only when hovering on top of the button, and in JQueryUI examples there's no help on achieving this scenario. How do I differ from hover effect and make it work with click event of the button? How can I achieve this?

I'm using `jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js` and `jquery-1.8.2.js` for this.

**HTML Code:**
I want to display the message on top of this input box

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="myInput" value="0" size="7" />
```

The button which I click in-order to popup tooltip

```
<input id="myBtn" type="submit" name="myBtn" value="myBtn" title="this is not used" class="myBtn" />
```

**JQuery Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myBtn").tooltip({
               content: function () {
                  return '<span id="msg">Message</span>';
               },
               position: {
                  my: "center bottom",
                  at: "center top"
               }
            });
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest way is to remove the title attribute of `myBtn` and move your tooltip onto another element. For example:

```
<a id="myTooltip" title="Message"></a>
```

Then you can do:

```
$('#myTooltip').tooltip({
    //use 'of' to link the tooltip to your specified input
    position: { of: '#myInput', my: 'left center', at: 'left center' }
});

$('#myBtn').click(function () {
    $('#myTooltip').tooltip('open');
});
```

Similarly you can close the tooltip with

```
$('#myTooltip').tooltip('close');
```

---

To automatically close the tooltip after opening you just need to call the `close` method inside the `open` event:

```
$('#myTooltip').tooltip({
    open: function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(e.target).tooltip('close');
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Using `e.target` (as `this` will not work inside the `open` event) and `setTimeout()` to set a time limit after which the tooltip will close.

Comment: I added the close event inside another user behavior and it works. Thx for the help @Elliott

Comment: what if i want to close the tooltip automatically after opening it programmatic?