# Jquery UI Tool Tip Trigger with Delayed Release

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

I am trying to use the jQuery Tool tip function and from the examples I am having issues altering the code for the function I am after.

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#forms

I have several coulored Circle area maps that I want a tool tip to pop up from when one is clicked on.

The following function works but it also pops up a tool tip when mousing over the element. Then when you click on it another tool tip pops up.

So What I need, is to change the function to only pop up "on click" and then to fade away after a few seconds.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {        
                        var tooltips = $( "[title]" ).tooltip();

                                $( "#01-001" ).click(function() {

                                        tooltips.tooltip( "open" );            
                                })  

                        });
```

HTML:

```
          <area id="01-001" shape="circle" coords="99,71,10" href="#" alt="01-001" data-maphilight='{"stroke":false,"fillColor":"FF0000","fillOpacity":1,"alwaysOn":true}' title="Tool Tip Messgae." />
```

Thanks Guys.

Samuel

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to wait until the click event to instantiate the tooltip. You're getting them on hover because you instantiated them all at once.

There's a detailed answer by [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13084046/1827560).